# Redirect .rar files to another folder using .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I moved .rar files to **old-files/** directory and I wanna redirect any url which ended by .rar to /old-files directory .

example:
redirect **[www.example.com/file.rar](http://www.example.com/file.rar)** to **[www.example.com/old-files/file.rar](http://www.example.com/old-files/file.rar)**

this is my code:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^.*/([^\.]+)\.rar/?  [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*).rar$ /old-files/$1.rar [R=301,NC,L]
```

but it's not working correctly , so any help ?!

and thank you